# Imazalil on citrus fruits

Tags: side-effects, cancer, food-safety

[Imazalil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enilconazole) is a fungicide, dangerous for our health. Widely used in agriculture, e.g. you can find Imazalil on lemons.
But it's no clear at all to me if risks are associated with eating, breathing, touching of this compound.

I use lemon and peel of it in my drinks everyday. In few words, I put Imazalil in my glass of water, coke and tea: how much is it dangerous for my health?

Comment: The wikipedia article you linked to answers your question.

Comment: could you explain better?

Comment: Read the "Hazards" section. It explains the known risks and the (US) government's assessment of those risks. Also, follow the links in the references for direct sources. It's unlikely anyone here will know more than what's in that article.